# Show that there is a sequence ${a_n}$ such that for every real number x, there is a subsequence of ${a_n}$ converging to x

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I came across this question in a textbook with no solutions and I'm having trouble with where to start. I'm thinking that somewhere I might need to use the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem but I am unsure of how to use it. I would be grateful for any help !

Comment: $$a_{2^n+k}=n(k-2^{n-1})2^{-n}\qquad 0\leqslant k<2^n\qquad n\geqslant0$$

Answer (score 4):

Just let $a_n$ be any enumeration of the rationals.